# Pexel's website API only seems to return a max of 8000 results... is there a way around this?

Tags: image, rest, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a bunch of images off a web site called Pexel using their API. I discovered their API results never give me a value of 'total_results' greater than 8000, although I'm sure they have more photos than that on their website.  I tried a bunch of really broad search terms, and I can never get the total_results above 8000.  I also kept pulling the next page, and confirmed it stopped returning results once total_results was reached.

If I want to run a search and download more than 8000 results, is there a way around this limitation? I'm also tempted to try another photo sharing website and see if they don't have an arbitrary limit like this.

Here's the documentation to the specific REST-API call I'm using:
https://www.pexels.com/api/documentation/?#photos-search

Comment: Update: No luck. I had a request for full API access supposedly approved, but I still hit the 8000 result limit. I'm not sure if the API is designed to allow a way around this.